# How can I add the output of a command as header in openresty?

Tags: nginx, lua, openresty

I'm trying to setup a proxy using openresty that will execute a command and add the output as an http header and pass the request with the original headers and body and the new header. I'm running the [openresty/openresty:1.15.8.3-bionic](https://hub.docker.com/layers/openresty/openresty/1.15.8.3-bionic/images/sha256-dfe63bfb9569ae92c45bee23a06cd8db78d6161991fd9b4bbe427d2d18e54e07?context=explore) docker image.

Here's my config:

```
                    daemon off;
                    error_log /dev/stdout debug;
                    events {
                      worker_connections  4096;
                    }
                    http {
                        access_log /dev/stdout;
                        server {
                            listen 8080;
                            server_name  localhost;
                            location / {
                                set_by_lua_block $res {
                                     local handle = io.popen('my-command')
                                     local result = handle:read('*a')
                                     handle:close()
                                     return result
                                }
                                proxy_pass http://server_host:server_port;
                                proxy_set_header MyHeader $res;
                            }
                        }
                    }
```

When I run the proxy with this configuration, my new header is passed to the proxied server correctly. However, the original request headers and body are not passed. When I replace the `proxy_set_header MyHeader $res;` with something like `proxy_set_header MyHeader 'some-static-value'`, original headers, body and the new header are passed to the proxied server. I tried adding `proxy_pass_request_body on;` and `proxy_pass_request_headers on;` to no avail.

Is there a way to achieve what I'm after?

Comment: Try removing the Lua part and setting the header to something static like "test"; if it still doesn't work, remove the `lua` tag and post that simplified example ;)

Comment: Setting the header to something static works, it works even if i keep everything as is and just change the `return result` in the lua block to `return 'test'`

Comment: Oh, right, the return code of the command probably has a newline and openresty doesn't sanitize that, so when it adds its own newline, you get two of them, which in HTTP means the end of the header block and the start of the actual content. Try removing trailing newlines (or any newlines, for that matter)

Comment: @DarkWiiPlayer yes, that was it! changing the `return result` to `return string.gsub(result, '%s+', '')` solved it. Thank you!